# Unsubscribe confirmation email fails when using Exchange as the mail server

Tags: email, unsubscribe

If a CiviCRM site is using MS Exchange to handle email, a user attempting to unsubscribe gets an error like:

*Mailing Error Failed to send data [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 554, response: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 0.35250:89230000,*

Answer (score 2):

I discovered this was because CiviCRM attempts to send the email from do-not-reply@ and the account used to send the email did not have the rights to send on behalf of that email address. You cure it by creating a shared mailbox called do-no-reply@ and give the outbound email account rights to send email from that mailbox.

Comment: The do-not-reply@domain.com is hard coded at: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/BAO/Domain.php#L339